# Como monitorar um arquivo em tempo real no Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd

Em implantação de serviços e aplicações em servidores, conseguir monitorar o arquivo de *log* vendo todas as atualizações assim que elas ocorrem, facilita bastante esta tarefa.

No Linux, utilizo o ***tail*** que só carrega o final do arquivo, sendo portanto excelente para lidar com arquivos grandes:

```
tail -f /usr/local/myservice/file.log
```

No Windows, existe alguma alternativa para o CMD?
Se não, qual alternativa fora do CMD?

Answer (score 3):

Via CMD, desconheço alguma solução, mas segue abaixo algumas alternativas:

Usando o **PowerShell**:

```
Get-Content arquivo.log –Wait
```

Se quiser fazer filtros, podemos usar outro comando concatenado chamado where:

```
Get-Content myTestLog.log -wait | where { $_ -match "WARNING" }
```

---

Particularmente gosto de usar o **[baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/)**, por ter a possibilidade, de criar regras de cores, assim coloco como regra a palavra "ERRO" e fica vermelho a linha, sempre que tiver a palavra, recomendo.

---

No artigo, [Tail a Log File on Windows & Linux](https://stackify.com/13-ways-to-tail-a-log-file-on-windows-unix/), pode encontrar mais alternativas.

Answer (score 2):

Se quiser continuar usando o `tail` você pode instalar o MinGw

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/

com ele você poderá executar o próprio comando.

`C:\>tail -f log.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use o comando abaixo para sempre monitorar a última linha do arquivo(no powershell)

```
>powershell
>Get-Content SEU_ARQUIVO –Wait
```